# Java Regex to convert "n't" into "not"

Tags: java, regex, replace, regex-negation, text-parsing

I am looking for a java regular expression to replace any string of the pattern, 
 `(a-z)+n't (word)` to `not_word`

For ex:

```
 "doesn't like" to "not_like"
 "I don't like" to "i not_like"
 "I don't like having dinner now" to "I not_like having dinner now"
```

I tried many things without success.

Comment: Show us your best attempt, them we can help with your code.

Comment: Why do you want to use Regex ? - it looks like a simple string replace will do.

Comment: I tried this. Pattern-([a-zA-Z]+)([n])(')([t])( )+([a-zA-Z]+) Replacement: not_$6 . While this works for a pattern that has a word after the negation word, it will not work for the sentence that end with negation word. eg: it's not working for sentence "please don't"

Comment: @SrivatsanNallazhagappan don't add that information as comment, instead add it to your question with [[edit]] option placed under it.

Comment: @SrivatsanNallazhagappan Can you show us some general cases of input and expected output since you didn't mentioned earlier about case where sentence ends with negation word. How program should react for such data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the regular expression:

```
[a-z]+n't\s*
```

e.g.

```
private static final Pattern REGEX_PATTERN = 
        Pattern.compile("[a-z]+n't\\s*", 
                        Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.MULTILINE);

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String input = "doesn't like\nI don't like\nI don't like having dinner now";

    System.out.println(
        REGEX_PATTERN.matcher(input).replaceAll("not_")
    );
}
```

Output:

```
not_like
I not_like
I not_like having dinner now
```

Comment: Thanks, its great. it works for me, I just replaced s+ with s* in your expr to allow zero or more spaces.

Comment: OK! Enjoy regex! Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

You need to change `(a-z)` into [class character](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) `[a-z]`, also if you want to be sure that there is other word after `[a-z]+n't` part you can

- add `\\S+` - non space characters - in `(` `)` brackets and use this [group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) in replacement - you can do it with `$x` where `x` is group number (in your case it will be probably `$1`)
- use [look-ahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html#lookahead) mechanism `(?=\\S+)` so this part will not be included in match, but will have to appear after `[a-z]+n't`.

Now to replace your data you can use for example something like this

```
String replacedString = yourString.replaceAll("yourRegex","yourReplacemet");
```

Comment: Sorry, I missed to add another input test case, please don't should be converted to please not_ The following expr works for all cases "[a-zA-Z]+n't\\s*" works. Thanks for the nice explanation

Comment: @SrivatsanNallazhagappan in that case you probably should make space optionally by adding `*` or `?` after it, and add word boundary `\\b` after `n't` to prevent matching this part in words that don't end with `n't` (if there are not such words in English then maybe there are other in other languages, in case if your data can have quotes from foreign sources).

Answer (score 1):

```
    String s = "I don't like having dinner now";
    s =s.replaceAll("(\\w+n't)\\s(\\w+)","not_$2");
    System.out.println(s);
```

output : I not_like having dinner now

Answer (score 0):

Use Pattern and Matcher, like this:

```
    String text    ="doesn't like"

    String patternString1 = "([a-zA-Z]+n't )";

    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(patternString1);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);

    String replaceAll = matcher.replaceAll("not_");
    System.out.println("replaceAll   = " + replaceAll);
```

The outcome will be: "not_like"

the [a-zA-Z] makes sure that it also replaces the beginning of the word, or else it would have output "doesnot_like".

Also notice the space after +n't. So that the space between the words is removed and the output is not_like as you requested instead of not_ like

Remember to include java.util.regex.Matcher and java.util.regex.Pattern!

Comment: @SrivatsanNallazhagappan Feel free to accept this as the correct answer if it solved your problem, as it could help others with the same problem.